# function not returning the expected output

Tags: c++

I wrote a simple function that accepts a string and then it reverses the string and checks if the string is 
palindrome, in other words if the string is symmetrical if yes it return true else it returns false

the program runs without any errors but it returns three zeros each one for every time the function 
is called

```
#include <iostream>
// Define is_palindrome() here:
bool  is_palindrome(std::string text ) {
        //std::cout << text << std::endl;
        std::string rev_text = "";       //  declare a string var to save the reversed word
        // reverse the number with a loop
        for (int i =text.size(); i >= 0; i--) {
                rev_text += text[i];
        }
        std::cout << text << "  " << rev_text << std::endl; 
        // check if the reversed number is equal to the origianl provided 
        if (rev_text == text) {
                return true;
        }
        else if  ( rev_text != text ) {
                return false; 
        }
}
int main() {
  std::cout << is_palindrome("10101") << "\n";
  std::cout << is_palindrome("002200") << "\n";
  std::cout << is_palindrome("5620265") << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i =text.size(); i >= 0; i--) {
    rev_text += text[i];
}
```

This loop starts with `i == text.size()`, meaning that you access `text[text.size()]` in the first iteration. That is one-past-the-end of the string and therefore always returns `'\0'`.

You add that as first element to `rev_text`. So the result contains this extra character that is not in the original.

To fix this, I suggest you use iterators:

```
for(auto it = text.rbegin(); it != text.rend(); it++) {
    rev_text += *it;
}
```

`rbegin()` and `rend()` give you iterators that traverse the vector in reverse direction.

Or even simpler using `<algorithm>`:

```
auto rev_text = text;
std::reverse(rev_text.begin(), rev_text.end());
```

Comment: how can I fix this or modify it in any way to get the ones and zeros that I need

Comment: @tochka See edit. I recommend using iterators instead of indices, because there are sum subtleties with the index iteration in reverse direction.